# Show overlay only when the dropdown is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I got this working but only if I click on the button. Whenever I click outside of the button, the overlay `active` class doesn't work as intended.

I would like to show the 'overlay active` class only when the dropdown is shown.

**DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/Laxu6s0n/**

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                   YOLO
                </button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">111</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">222</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
<p>This is a body</p>
<div class="overlay">
I'm an overlay
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
    $('.overlay').toggleClass('active');
});
```

CSS:

```
.overlay.active {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 45px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropdown-menu` is not a child of `dropdown-toggle` so when you click on the menu it doesn't trigger your click function so you will just need to add a click event to your `dropdown-item`.

```
$(".dropdown-toggle, .dropdown-item").click(function () {
    $('.overlay').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Then to close the overlay if clicked outside of the dropdown you will need to add a listener to the window.

```
$(window).on('click', function(e) {
   if ($('.overlay').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.overlay').removeClass('active')
   }
})
```

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't work. Click on the button, then click anywhere outside of the button/dropdown and you will notice that the `overlay` doesn't work as intended anymore. See Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dzLmnxyk/

Comment: ah I see. I will take another look

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're toggling the class on clicking on the dropdown. Not on clicking anywhere else. It's easily solved by adding an additional event handler that only removes the class:

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.id != 'dropdownMenuButton'){
        $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
    }
});`
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't get it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/myhoqk1r/

Comment: @ElaineByene I said to add it. Not replace it. Works perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/u28b13zr/